# Solving a Poisson equation analytically

Tags: electrostatics, integration

I have a programme for numerical solutions of the 3D Poisson equation. Due to the special input requirements I would need to test this against a special analytical case. It is this:

$$ \nabla^2 \phi = r e^{-2r} \cos^2\theta ,$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ and theta is given by the usual spherical coordinate $z=r\cos\theta$. For the boundary condition we can use that $\phi$ is vanishing quickly.

I have tried to make an Ansatz of $\phi := f(r,\theta) \exp(-2r)$ and to use the [Laplacian in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions), but the equation becomes large and very unhandy. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that this equation has an analytical solution?

Comment: Could you please provide the motivation behind you trying to solve this particular PDE?

Comment: @schris38 I tried to do that by writing: "Due to the special input requirements I would need to test this against a special analytical case." A full sufficient motivation would require about the tenfold of the text written so far. But I can try a scetch if you think it's vital.

Comment: @Mauricio No, I am not.

Comment: Okay, so I would try if I were you an ansatz of the form $\phi=\frac{f(r,\theta)}{r}e^{-2r}$, as this will help you get rid of the exponential factors and it will produce less factors if you use the second form of the Laplacian operator in the link you provide. Then, by performing the calculations, one arrives at an equation that can not be tackled with separation of variables... So, this is the reason I was asking for the motivation... Because there might be an error in what you are reading perhaps, because I also am starting to belive that there is no solution...

Comment: Why not test with an easier analytic case? Start with some kind of complicated function for $\phi$ and then calculate the source from it (right hand side), which is the easier direction.

Comment: @Alwin Because the actual input comes from an output of a quantum chemistry program which in turn generates only (approximate solutions) for single atom electronic structure and so on.

Comment: Sure, but you can (and should) test your Poisson solver using other known solutions. You can also try comparing the output of your Poisson solver with other solvers. In your particular case I believe you should be able to make progress using a multipole expansion

Comment: @Alwin Yes, I definitely will. Thanks for suggestions!